# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook, ssl, dotnetopenauth

I've had social sign-in using Facebook implemented in Production for some time. As of this morning, it is no longer working for me. I am getting the same error in dev (which has no SSL) and in production, which is hosted on Azure Web Sites, and does use SSL.

Here's the error I'm seeing:

`[WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.]
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request) +283
   System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address) +100
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.FacebookClient.QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, String authorizationCode) +350
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuth2Client.VerifyAuthentication(HttpContextBase context, Uri returnPageUrl) +202
   DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.OpenAuthSecurityManager.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +411
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthenticationCore(HttpContextBase context, String returnUrl) +189
   Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(String returnUrl) +139`

Anyone else seeing this? My Google login continues to work just fine.

Comment: Are you still using SSL3? SSL3 has been disabled on all of Facebook's endpoints due to http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/70719/ssl3-poodle-vulnerability

Comment: Looks like I was. I tried what Mikejh99 suggested, but am still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Igy said, this is due to SSLv3 being disabled by Facebook because of the POODLE exploit.

I had the same thing happen to an app that connects to Twitter. I fixed it by adding this line of code to use TLS. I'm not sure this is the best solution, but it works for now.

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention this, but I added that line to Application_Start of global.asax

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helped. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I set a breakpoint to make sure that the application is indeed restarting and it is getting hit, unfortunately, I'm still getting the same exception.

Comment: For good measure, I also tried `Tsl` and `Tsl11`. Same result.

Comment: This line of code before every web request using https, worked for me. All facebook,linkedin and twitter connect/post were affected

Comment: As a side note, my setting kept getting reverted. I used [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to add my solution folder to the assembly and then used "Find usages" on `SecurityProtocol`. Turns out there was a 3rd-party plugin that had it hardcoded to use `Ssl3` and was causing a further problem.

Comment: correction: "add my solution folder to the assembly list"

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has dropped support for SSL 3.0 across the Facebook Platform API and the Real-Time Updates API, after a vulnerability in the protocol was revealed publicly on October 14, 2014 (http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html).

Old versions of the PHP SDK (Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1 and older) that used SSL 3.0 will now no longer work.

All developers should upgrade to Facebook SDK 3.2.3 or greater. SDK 4.0.0 is recommended.

- PHP SDK 3.2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/3.2.3
- PHP SDK 4.0.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0
- Dev Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#disable-ssl-v30

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem in a live environment. All accounts were changed at the same time:

- Facebook
- Twiter
- LinkedIn

For twitter I think only needed would be to update Twitterizer.dll or the latest 3rd party Twitter library and check the code changes.

for LinkedIn it would be interesting to use OAuthv2 (or the last one, I do not remember the version release) but i remember it is very very difficult to solve.

For Facebook the same, change the SDK to the last one and relearn the library changes.

October 15th 2014 was planned on August that this was going to happen.

regards,

Isy

Answer (score 0):

why would setting the SecurityProtocol to TLS be a solution? .net should anyway negotiate the highest possible protocol with the server and if TLS is an option prefer that one over SSL, shouldn't it?!

Comment: Yes, but I had a third party library that was overriding the default and specifically requesting SSL only.